# How to get content to respond to sidebar open or close?

Tags: html, css, slidetoggle, sidebar, togglebutton

Ok, to start off I know that this has been asked before but my sidebar works differently to others with a similar question.

So back to my question. I have the below sidebar on a website I'm making, it uses two divs with one overlapping the other when toggled by button. (the content of the page at the moment isn't inside the second div, but on top because it was easier to work with). So how do I have the page content fit the new window size when the sidebar is open and then go back when it is closed?

```css
#A,
#B {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 800ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 800ms;
  -moz-transition: all 800ms;
  -ms-transition: all 800ms;
  -o-transition: all 800ms;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#A {
  top: 0px;
  width: 14em;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: #939393;
  border: solid #000000 2px;
}

#B {
  top: 0px;
  left: 14em;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: #3b3f45;
}

/*Hide the checkbox*/
#toggle {
  display: none;
}
.toggle label:hover, .toggle label:active, .toggle input:hover+label, .toggle input:active+label {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.toggle label {
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /*Set the left position to the same as the sidebar */
  left: 14em;     
  margin: 8em 1.5% 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 800ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 800ms;
  -moz-transition: all 800ms;
  -ms-transition: all 800ms;
  -o-transition: all 800ms;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  background: #75787c;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Initial sidebar state */
#toggle ~ #A {
  left: 0;
}

/*move both containers on toggle*/
#toggle:checked ~ #A,
#toggle:checked ~ #B {
  left: -14em;
}

/*move label to follow sidebar animation*/
#toggle:checked,
#toggle:checked ~ label {
  left: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <div id="A">
    </div>
  <input id="toggle" type="checkbox" checked>
  <label for="toggle">Menu</label>
  <div id="B">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What makes you think the content needs fitting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When sidebar is open content elements move across to fit new content size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666071/when-sidebar-is-open-content-elements-move-across-to-fit-new-content-size)

Comment: please don't ask your questions multiple times

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q6mgjq2e/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are using the selector `~` incorrectly

> The `element1 ~ element2` selector matches occurrences of `element2` that
>   are preceded by `element1`.
>
> Both elements must have the same parent, but `element2` does not have to
>   be immediately preceded by `element1`.
>
> **Example**
>
> Set a background color for all `<ul>` elements that are preceded by a `<p>` element with the same parent:
>
> ```
> p ~ ul {
>     background: #ff0000;
> }
> ```

In your case `#toggle ~ #A` and `#toggle:checked ~ #A` are not being applied because `#A` is not preceded by `#toggle`.

So just change the position of `#A` in the DOM like this:

```css
#A, #B {
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 800ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms;
    -moz-transition: all 800ms;
    -ms-transition: all 800ms;
    -o-transition: all 800ms;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /*The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin*/
}
#A {
    top: 0px;
    width: 14em;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: #939393;
    border: solid #000000 2px;
}
#B {
    top: 0px;
    left: 14em;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: #3b3f45;
}
/*Hide the checkbox*/
 #toggle {
    display: none;
}
.toggle label:hover, .toggle label:active, .toggle input:hover+label, .toggle input:active+label {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.toggle label {
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 4px;
    /*Set the left position to the same as the sidebar */
    left: 14em;
    margin: 8em 1.5% 5px;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: all 800ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms;
    -moz-transition: all 800ms;
    -ms-transition: all 800ms;
    -o-transition: all 800ms;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    background: #75787c;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Initial sidebar state */
 #toggle ~ #A {
    left: 0;
}
/*move both containers on toggle*/
 #toggle:checked ~ #A, #toggle:checked ~ #B {
    left: -14em;
}
/*move label to follow sidebar animation*/
 #toggle:checked, #toggle:checked ~ label {
    left: 0;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
    <input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
    <label for="toggle">Menu</label>
    <div id="A"></div>
    <div id="B"></div>
</div>
```

Note that I also set `box-sizing: border-box` to `#A, #B` to include the borders in the calculation of the width(14em). If you remove it you can see how the `border-right` of `#A` is not seen when you open it.